# TimeSheet to restrict meeting hall booking with same date's

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

How to prevent from single room booking with same date by different users?

I want to create a list, when ever item is added with start(date & time) to end(date & time's) it should book the meeting hall. If anyone is trying to book the same room with in between that particular time then it should block the room.

**For Ex:** First person has booked at 12/09/2017 10:00 to 12:00 AM & second person is trying to book the same room in between 11:00 to 01:00 AM it should display a message "Room has been Booked choose another room".

Please Help me,

***Thanks in Advance.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [Reservation of Resources](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-reservation-of-resources-in-a-calendar-0bdb58b9-db48-4c9f-b3f4-b2052f0576bc)  feature in SharePoint for calendars that will do what you are looking for.  This is an OOTB function, so no code needed for this.